# Fast image smoothing in C

Tags: c, image, optimization

Problem: Given a square matrix, A, whose dimension, N, is a divisor of 64, find a fast way to smoothe A by letting a 3 x 3 grid slide over the A, s.t. for each entry A_{ij}, we replace this with the average of the 8 nearby neighbors.

My solution: Let's assume A is a 4x4 matrix, we initialize as:

`int A[NxN] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}`

Which is equivalent to:

[image]

In the first iteration, we see A_ij is equivalent to 0, which is in the center of the 3x3 matrix. We realize that indices (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,3) of the 3x3 matrix is trying to find numbers not existing. Therefore, we see that the result must be that if $A_{ij}$ = 0, then we must replace it by $0+1+4+5 = \frac{10}{4}$.

Next iteration, we see A_ij is equivalent to 1, which is now the new center of the 3x3 matrix, and we see that the numbers to be included in the averaging is: 0,1,2,4,5,6.

So when we are in a corner of our matrix, A, we need 4 numbers for averaging, in the top of the matrix, we need 6 numbers, and if A_{ij} = 6, meaning in the middle of the matrix, we will need 9 numbers.

What I am trying to find is a general pattern for these sequences of needed numbers in order to do this in hopefully a single \texttt{for loop}.

I found that when i % dim == 0, we are in the left side of the matrix, when i % dim == 3 we are in the left side, but I have tried to find a general index pattern to define my averaging functions to pair with my if conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int smooth(int dim);

int main() {

    smooth(4);
}


int smooth(int dim) {
    int A[16] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    int K[dim*dim]; // Replacement array, otherwise we average averages
    

    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) 
        {
            // Corner cases
            if ((i % dim == 0 && j % dim == 0) || (i % dim == dim - 1 && j % dim == 0) || (i % dim == 0 && j % dim == dim -1) || (i % dim == dim -1 && j % dim == dim-1))
            { 
                // Average function on corners
            }

            // else if not corner and in "edge row", top/bottom {
                  // Average 6 numbers  

            }

        

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using a confusing number of "$". I guess for unsuccessful formatting attempts. Please [edit] and use this info. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Yunnosch My apologies - This is the LaTeX way of writing math, which works on other stack exchange sites. I will update now.

Comment: How about NOT working on the edge with the generic formula and using specifcs for the four edges?

Comment: If you insist on processing all pixels with the same formula then you introduce virtual edges, which fill the "gaps" for processing actual edge pixels. You just need to spend some thoughts on which values to use. Maybe the same value as the neighbouring actual edge pixel.

Comment: @Yunnosch I was thinking of defining 4 macros to average, one for each case. I was just wondering if someone could spot a pattern of indices to use for each case to insert under my conditionals.

Comment: The pattern is extremely simple if you get the edges right. You ask about "fast", which is served best by NOT having special case detection inside the loop. Setup the loop or loops so that only a single calculation is used unconditionally.

Comment: The first iteration is the corner case, use indices: 0 1 4 5. 
Next iteration is the top-case, use indices: 0 1 2 4 5 6.
Next iteration is a top-case too, use: 1 2 3 5 6 7 

I am failing to see the simple pattern.

Comment: Only if you insist on setting up your loop that way. Or if you insist on applying the non-corner case calculation to the corner case.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am completely open to any kinds of solutions, as I have realized mine does not work. I would ideally love to work with 1 function to average, which could take care of all cases.

Comment: For speed, process the corners (0,3,12,15) individually, apply one dedicated edge case calculation each to the non-corner-edges (1-2, 4-8, 13-14, 7-11) and apply one unconditional (i.e. no `if` inside) to the center rest (5-6-9-19). Or make the picture bigger by 2 in x and y. Fill the newly added corners and edges with sensible values and then apply one unconditional formula to all of the original picture.

Comment: If that makes sense to you (I do not know all your indirect requirements) let me know. I would put it into an answer then.

Comment: Aside: you must build a *separate* image, not "replace" a pixel, or you'll be averaging averages.

Comment: @WeatherVane Very good input! 

So, I agree with Yunnosch, this must be the way to go. Now I just have to introduce some code-motion and loop unrolling. If we look at the case of A being a 8x8 matrix, then we can't use the general i % dim == 1 to check for left sides, as i % dim will be 7 for the entirety of the left-most row.

Comment: Use two nested loops to setup a rectangular subset of your matrix. Calculate the 1D index from the 2 loop counters.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am afraid I am not fully sure of what you mean here. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: You seem to be planning on using a single loop with some magic math to cover an essential 2D structured input. I recommend to simplify your life by using a 2D method. Use two loops, one y, the other, nested inside, doing x. Setup the loops with correct length for height and width. Then calculate the 1D index from the two loop counters. I could create a detailed code proposal, but only if first you show a [mre] of your 1D approach. That way I have a foundation of input and code structure which matches your situation.

Comment: @Yunnosch I will add what I have now -- it's nowhere near functional yet. I do see the double for-loop being inevitable, I'll try to jot it down really fast! Thanks a lot for your responses.

Comment: Not "inevitable", but probably less of a challenge.

Comment: @Yunnosch Tried very fast to show a reproducable code example. Just did it the for corner cases, with commented functions. I don't know how i retrieve the correct "numbers" from my 1D array, when using 2D indexing, though.

Comment: Suppose the row length of the image is 60, and you have allowed for padding, and are using a 1D array. The pixel at row 7, column 42 is at `array[i = 7*60 + 42]`. Unrolling the neighbours loop, the 8 neighbours of the pixel at `array[i]` are at `array[i-61]`, `array[i-60]`, `array[i-59]`, `array[i-1]`, `array[i+1]`, `array[i+59]`, `array[i+60]` and `array[i+61]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The length will always be a divisor of 64 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your mre is a bit theoretical, I will leave all parts which are not practically plausible out of this. They obviously only serve to provide a MRE quick.

Interpret your input as 2D.

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15
```

More abstractly as

```
 0              ...  (      0*dim + (dim-1))
(1       * dim) ...  (      1*dim + (dim-1))
(2       * dim) ...  (      2*dim + (dim-1))
                 .
                 .
                 .
((dim-1) * dim) ...  ((dim-1)*dim + (dim-1))
```

Here is the structure I propose for your function

```
int smooth(int dim)
{
    int A[16] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}; //obvious MRE weirdness, ignored
    int K[dim*dim]; // Replacement array, otherwise we average averages
    
    // Corner cases
    K[0]            = A[0];           /* dummy, to be calculated */
    K[dim-1]        = A[dim-1];       /* dummy, to be calculated */
    K[dim*(dim-1)]  = A[dim*(dim-1)]; /* dummy, to be calculated */
    K[dim*dim-1]    = A[dim*dim-1];   /* dummy, to be calculated */

    for (int i = 0; i < dim-2; i++)
    {
        // edge cases
        {
            K[1+i]             = A[1+i];             /* dummy, average to be calculated */
            K[dim*(1+i)]       = A[dim*(1+i)];       /* dummy, average to be calculated */
            K[dim*(1+i)+dim-1] = A[dim*(1+i)+dim-1]; /* dummy, average to be calculated */
            K[dim*(dim-1)+i+1] = A[dim*(dim-1)+i+1]; /* dummy, average to be calculated */ 
        }

        // center part
        for (int j = 0; j < dim-2; j++) 
        {
            K[(i+1)*dim+1+j] = A[(i+1)*dim+1+j]; /* dummy, average to be calculated */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For all cases of `A[...]; /* dummy, average to be calculated */` you can use the same index for reading from `A` as for writing into `K` and

- subtract 1 to get to the pixel to the left
- add one to get to the pixel to the right
- add dim to get to the pixel below
- subtract dim to get to the pixel above
- do that for all neigbouring pixels you decide to use
- sum the values up to determine the average

In all cases where you need a neighbour pixel you will always arrive at a valid pixel, because either there is one or you are not going to need it.

(Note: I strictly practice starting for loops from 0 and count up with `<needed_length`. There is an alternative to start from 1 and count up to needed length +1. It will in this case here make the index calculations read easier. This is a matter of habits. I come from an environment where you have to prepare strong reasoning for loops not starting at 0. Habits are hard to shed. Going through the alternative concept will probably provide you with some helpful learning opportunity.)